# Send http request with html button

Tags: php, html, button

i have created a html button like this:

`<html><button onclick=''>Send request to server</button></html>`

And when that button has been clicked i want to send request to server, that looks very similar to this:

```
$request = new HttpRequest('$url', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
                $request->send();
```

How can i make button execute these php lines when it was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't get Client side vs Server side. Common problem.

PHP is a server side language, meaning it lives on the server.

HTML is client side, it's not even a programming language but a mark up language to display content.

Everytim you request a page, that request enters a webserver, that webserver then has a PHP file that handles the request and sends back a HTML file.

Everytime you want the server (the php files) to do something, you have to send a request.

So, how do we send a request? Different options here:

A simple GET request can be send using a button, or an anchor () or a form. But, know that they not only send a request, they direct the current webpage to the given URL, thus creating a request.

When using a Form, one could also send a POST, DELETE, PUT, ... request to the server.

Sometimes however, you want to send a request to the server, without refreshing/directing the page of the user. This can't be done using HTML.
But, there is JavaScript that can help us a lot.

The technique used here is called AJAX and you can read a lot about is on the internet ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTP mechanism: don't use a `<button>` but a `<form action="_your_php_file_" method="_POST_OR_GET_">` with an `<input type="submit">` to replace the button.

Set in the `<form>` if you want to generate a `POST` or a `GET` request, and add some `<input type="hidden" name="..." value="...">` in order to add parameters to the request it will generates.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `<FORM`> tag or javascript(ajax) to send a GET request to the server.